# Flex - Drag and Drop of list items using keyboard

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, keyboard, drag

been stuck on this for a couple of days. I'm attempting to implement drag and drop between lists using keyboard event handlers. It's not going well. This is what I have atm -

```
        private function keyboardHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
            if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){
                var list : List = List(event.currentTarget);
                var dragInitiator:UIComponent = UIComponent(list.indexToItemRenderer(list.selectedIndex));
                var ds:DragSource = new DragSource();
                ds.addData(list.selectedItem, "listItem");
                DragManager.doDrag(dragInitiator, ds, new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));
            }
        }

<s:Panel title="EXAMPLE"
         width="75%" height="75%" 
         horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
    <s:VGroup left="10" right="10" top="10" bottom="10">
        <s:Label text="DRAG" />
        <mx:List id="dragSource" width="100%" color="blue"
                 keyDown="keyboardHandler(event)"
                 change="selectedListItem = List(event.currentTarget).selectedItem"
                 dataProvider="{mystates.state}"/>
        <s:Label text="DROP" />
        <mx:List id="dropSource" width="100%" color="blue"
                 keyDown="keyboardHandler(event)"
                 dataProvider="{mystates.state}" dropEnabled="true"/>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Panel>
```

The drag is seemingly being initialized, but it does not let me drop on the target list (using the mouse currently for testing purposes). Using the debugger - the variables once the keyboard handler is fired are as follows:

dragInitatior - mx.controls.listClasses.ListItemRenderer (@90c83c1)
ds - mx.core.DragSource (@8fe5f01)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fudge it sort of and got the drag started by simulating a MouseDown event on my list item.

```
private function customDrag(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
            if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){
                var selectedItem:IListItemRenderer = myList.indexToItemRenderer(myList.selectedIndex);
                selectedItem.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN));
            }
        }
```

Not having much luck executing a dragDrop event via keyboard on my target container though.